# Coding under the influence

Tags: discussion, markdown, fun

How<sup>does<sup>one<sup>code</sup>when</sup>they</sup>have<sup>been<sup>drinking<sup>all</sup>night?</sup>Don't</sup>they<sup>feel<sup>sick<sup>and<sup>nauseous?</sup>I mean</sup>come on dude!</sup>You cant keep</sup>looking<sup>at this<sup>small<sup>text! right?</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Too much unicoins?

Comment: I've decided to get back at markdown for all the times it's been difficult...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about unicoins.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I'll bribe you with unicoins for you to turn a blind hoof...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I can't read such small letters.

Comment: @BЈовић - *you* seem to be off-topic because I can not read/pronounce your username ;)

Answer (score 11):

You need to <sup>read<sup>the<sup>warning</sup>on<sup>the</sup></sup><sup>back<sup>of<sup>the</sup></sup></sup></sup>bottle.

I'm pretty sure "Do not operate machinery when under the influence of alcoholic beverages" also applies to IE 11. You need to stay away from that stuff.

Comment: I assume *that stuff* refers to IE11, not to alcoholic beverages.

Answer (score 5):

```
             ____                  
            |    |                 
            |    |                 
            |____|                 
            |    |                 
            (    )                 
            )    (                 
          .'      `.               
         /          \              
        |------------|             
        |JACK DANIELS|             
        |    ----    |             
        |   (No.7)   |             
        |    ----    |             
        | Tennessee  |             
        |  WHISKEY   |             
        |  40% Vol.  |             
        |------------|             
        |____________|dp
```

(found [here](http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=objects/bottles) ;))